# Add class an element placed before another element

Tags: jquery

Please help me to add class. my code is given below:

```html
<p>some conent goes here</p>
<p>some conent goes here</p>
<p>some conent goes here</p>
<p>some conent goes here</p>

<ul>
    <li>My list item</li>
    <li>My list item</li>
    <li>My list item</li>
</ul>
```

I want to add a class on "p" just placed before the `<ul>`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/addclass?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [`prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/)

```
$("ul").prevAll("p").addClass("someClass");
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/g5L2n73y/)

If you want to target a single `p` element that is present above `UL`, then you have to use `prev()`

```
 $("ul").prev("p").addClass("someClass");
```

Also note that, `prev` would select the immediate previous sibling, not the one which is present after some elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('ul').prev().addClass('myClass');
```